# Which word to use: "polyglotte" or "multilingue"?

Tags: usage, grec, curriculum-vitae

I know the words *bilingue*, *trilingue*, *quadrilingue*, etc.
For a person who masters several languages one can use *multilingue* and *polyglotte*.
My colleagues and HR staff suggested to  me that I should avoid the use of *polyglotte* in CVs, dossiers de postulation and the like, and use *multilingue* instead.
However, I don't get the reason for that as on the basis of this [diagram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=multilingue%2Cpolyglotte&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cmultilingue%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cpolyglotte%3B%2Cc0), both  words are in use.

So can one use *polyglotte* or not? In addition, talking about the aforementioned diagram, can someone explain the reason for the increasing usage of *multilingue* after the 1960s and why after the middle 80s *polyglotte* seems to fall into disuse?

Comment: I truly have no idea, but it seemed to me that councellors of any kind are sometimes coming up with these little do's & don'ts that hardly make sense and are forgotten as quickly as they came around. Now there might be more to this in particular, but I don't know what it is (and frankly, I wouldn't lose sleep on this either)... But who knows?

Comment: Both words are used. "polyglotte" sound older but can still be use

Comment: for some reasons no one knows, multilingue seems to be prefered nowadays; I do think that most people (like the aforementioned “colleagues and HR staff”), are not cultivated enough to differentiate words coming from latin (multilingue, multicolore) and from greek (polyglotte, polychrome). If I may: polyglotte only for persons, multlingue for instance for environment, studies, methods and so one (« Une édition bilingue » as much as « des interlocuteurs bilingues » et bien sûr « Je suis trilingue tant à l'écrit qu'à l'oral »).

Comment: I've never heard of "multilingue" being better. I would actually prefer to read "polyglotte" in a CV - as @5915961T says it is totally unambiguous.

Comment: Stating that MOST people are not cultivated enough to tell the difference between greek and latin roots is: A) a bit condescending; B) quite possibly false; C) irrelevant. Let me bring some data to confirm my last point, since it could be perceived as a matter of opinion: some unique latin roots have created multiple French words with sometimes widely separated acceptions. [Here](http://www.axl.cefan.ulaval.ca/francophonie/HIST_FR_s92_Emprunts.htm#3._Lapport_des_langues_anciennes_au_fran%C3%A7ais_) are a few examples. Thus, arguing on the etymology is somewhat beside the point.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would avoid both *polyglotte* and *multilingue* in a resume.

Both are imprecise so require more details anyway. The former might be perceived as a brag too. The second is better, but in my experience much more used when referring to a document, a media, or even a job description than a person.

The usage is to have a "Language" section. You can use *bilingue* or *trilingue* in it but only if you are really fluent in two or three languages. e.g. :

> Langues:
>
> Bilingue français/allemand
>   ..

In the usual case, you can simply list all languages you are familiar with and state your level in each one, e.g.:

> Langues :
>
> Grec : langue maternelle
>   Anglais et français : courant
>   Allemand : compris, bonnes notions
>   Russe : scolaire
>   ...

Add details like diplomas, certificates, levels achieved. (A/B/C or A1/A2/B1/B2...), time spent and activity in relevant countries.

Answer (score 6):

Pourquoi ne pas s'en tenir à une définition de dictionnaire (TLFi) ? « Multilingue » concerne le parler de trois langues au moins et apprises en tant que langues maternelles. « Polyglotte » étant plus général, signifie  « qui parle au moins deux langues ».

Cependant les dictionnaires Larousse et reverso font de « multilingue », « plurilingue » et « polyglotte » des synonymes.

Ce qui concerne vos collègues dans leur parti pris à vouloir reléguer le mot « polyglotte » aux marges du langage ne correspond pas aux définitions des dictionnaires. Il semble qu'ils soient plutôt enclins à « s'aligner » sur l' anglais « multilingual ». Il est bien spécifié que « multilingue » implique au moins trois langues, toutes des langues maternelles. Il y a là une distinction qui a été déterminée une fois pour toutes et très certainement utilisée selon cette définition.

On constate évidemment une incohérence dans l'utilisation de « multilingue » selon la définition du TLFi en cela que « bilingue  », «  trilingue », « quadrilingue », etc. impliquent des langues apprises d'une façon quelconque (voir les définitions). D'un autre côté il existe un usage établi (selon le TLFi) et utiliser « multilingue » en dépit de cet usage décroit la fonctionnalité de la langue française si cet usage est plus important que l'usage recommandé par vos collègues, lequel, de toute évidence se trouve aussi ; comme il est difficile de savoir quel est l'usage le plus important il est impossible de faire un choix selon ce critère.

Cependant, en choisissant « polyglotte », mot auxquel n'est attaché aucune notion spéciale et qui signifie simplement « plusieurs langues », on n'introduit dans son texte aucune ambigüité désagréable. Néanmoins, on peut adopter le point de vue que le terme « multilingue » est plus approprié en cela qu'il communique l'idée de langue directement  alors que le terme « glotte » n'évoque à l'utilisateur courant du langage rien d'autre qu'un organe assez peu connecté avec l'expression verbale. En d'autres termes on peut vouloir contribuer à une plus grande fonctionnalité du langage dans ce sens. Donc si on pense qu'augmenter la fonctionnalité ainsi en compense largement la perte  dans le sens de détruire une correspondance sans ambigüité mais dont le volume des occurrences est négligeable on peut choisir « multilingue » (si toutefois la scrupulosité que cela implique n'est pas trouvée excessive).

En conclusion, il peut être dit qu'il n'y a pas de choix idéal et « l'alignement » sur l'anglais n'est qu'une solution qui vise à faire du français non pas une langue intègre mais un calque de l'anglais (en particulier facile à traduire; critère majeure ?), bien que dans le présent cas ce choix vienne avec le bonus d'une plus grande fonctionnalité selon un certain point de vue abordé ci-dessus.

Comment: @dimitris J'ai ajouté des commentaires à ce problème d'utilisation du subjonctif que vous débattiez avec aCOSwt et comme il n'y a pas de réactions de votre part il me semble que je doive mal utiliser le système de notification. Est-ce le cas ?

Comment: Bon, ce ne sont pas tous des mots courants, beaucoup sont limités à un usage savant ou professionnel, mais voici le préfixe [*gloss-*](http://cnrtl.fr/definition/gloss-), où il est par ailleurs question par ricochet du terme *glose*, sans doute un peu plus commun.

Comment: @LPH Je vais voir les commentaires tout de suite:-)!

Comment: Par ailleurs, la page de synonymie de [multilingue](http://cnrtl.fr/synonymie/multilingue) au TLFi. En dépit de définitions quelque peu différentes, les deux concepts sont très liés. Un autre [lien](https://www.btb.termiumplus.gc.ca/tpv2guides/guides/clefsfp/index-fra.html?lang=fra&lettr=indx_catlog_m&page=90T8SGYw0Lm8.html) vers Termium, où les termes sont considérés comme équivalents, pouvant décrire aussi bien des personnes que des choses, avec le bémol que *multilingue* demeure adjectif, alors que *polyglotte* ou *plurilingue* peuvent être des noms.

Answer (score 3):

Personnellement, contrairement au commentaire précédent, je trouve que *polyglotte* sonne bien mieux que *multilingue* qui pour moi est une traduction de l'anglais *multilingual*. En anglais ça passe, mais en français, ça me semble trop proche d'une traduction mot à mot et pas assez française. Donc ça manque de localisation (terme de traduction applicant la traduction à sa culture cible) à mon goût.
De plus, je n'ai jamais entendu quelqu'un dire `je suis multilingue`. 
Mais `Je suis polyglotte` oui.

Comment: En français, *glotte* renvoie à la gorge, à la parole maîtrisée, alors que *multilingue* est un concept qui renvoie à l’écriture, il est donc tout à fait naturel de dire "je suis *polyglotte*" et d’écrire "Je suis *[bi|tri|…]lingue* …" dans un C.V.

Comment: Je ne suis pas d'accord sur le fait que multilingue ne renvoie qu'à l'écriture. La langue (Multilingue = plusieurs langues) renvoie également à une partie du corps faisant référence à l'élocution, tout comme la glotte de polyglotte... Pour moi ces deux rapprochement se valent. On peut écrire "bi/tri/quadrilingue" dans un CV en effet, mais "multilingue" sonne bizarre pour moi. Je ne l'ai jamais vu sur un CV. Si c'était le cas, ça me ferait plus penser à un robot multilingue, multi-fonctions, multi-taches... xD Mais ce n'est que mon avis.

Comment: Oui, on peut dire que l'on est polyglotte mais l'écrire dans un CV n'apporte rien. La seule chose qui pourra intéresser un employeur potentiel, c'est le détail : quelles langues sont connues et quel est le niveau atteint.